# Не могу установить tensorflow

Tags: python-3.6, install, tensorflow

У меня стоит python 3.6 пробовал установить tensorflow, но все время вылетает ошибка
" Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть идеи что не так?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

Список версий [tensorflow](https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow)

Источник: [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-using-pip)

Comment: теперь выдает другую ошибку вот скриншоты https://drive.google.com/open?id=1o3ThlNnee3k4aBBorfjVOdy_L0lYpWrg

Comment: @NTP, здравствуйте, по вашей ссылке получилось установить версию "0.12.0", но я не понимаю, как с помощью списка версий установить актуальную версию? Помогите, пожалуйста