# Как установитьTensorFlow на Windows?

Tags: python-3.x, windows

[Не могу установить tensorflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/879152/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-tensorflow)
Проверял этот ответ, установило как обычную библиотеку, но сам TensoFlow не работает. 
На компьютере стоит Windows 7 и работаю с  Pytho3.8 x64.